# Power BI: How can I log in as an admin?

Tags: powerbi

I signed up for a Get started free 60-day trial of Power BI Pro.

After the licence expired I want to upgrade the account and buy a licence but 
I went to the site https://portal.office.com and logged in.

But I get the message:

You can't revoke permission because this has been assigned to you as part of a subscription or an admin role.

My question is how can I get admin role to create the subscription.
The only person in the organization is me and no one else.

Comment: I would suggest to check with Microsoft Office Administrator (in your ORG) for permissions.

Comment: There is no organization, I am the only person working on this.